# update value after click on radio buttons and also need value in session variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two radio buttons. One is for **shipped** and other is for **not shipped**. If I click on first radio button, then amount 100 should be add in total price and if I click again in **not shipped** then amount 0 should add in old total price. And Updated value should be in session variable.

My code is:

```
<?php
 $_SESSION['fulltotalofferprice1']=$fulltotalofferprice;
?>
  <input name="shipping" type="radio" id="RadioGroup1_0" value="100" onclick="updateTotal(this.value)" />Shipped
  <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="0" id="RadioGroup1_0" checked="checked" onclick="updateTotal(this.value);" />Not Shipped

<tr><td>total Offer price: </td><td><span id="total"></span></td></tr>
```

My javascript is:

```
<script>
var total_without_shipping = '<?php echo $_SESSION['fulltotalofferprice1'];?>';

function updateTotal(shipping_cost) {
var total_cost = total_without_shipping + shipping_cost;
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total_cost;

}
</script>
```

And I also need updated price in session. By which I can use it for further pages.

Comment: To update something in the PHP session, you have to perform a backend call, either through AJAX or posting the whole session. And what's about the updated price listing on the page itself - what is not working with the code you provided?

Comment: Thank you for reply...It is not giving true calculation.

Comment: ....but instead?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php - without it, you don't have $_SESSION - but after that, your code doesn't make sense - - where are you getting $fulltotalofferprice in your first line???

Comment: Thankyou for reply...$fulltotalofferprice is coming from database query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you might want something like that:

First, let's remove the `onclick` from the radios, the `id`'s too, because the `id` attribute should **always** be unique in a document:

```
<?php
 $_SESSION['fulltotalofferprice1']=$fulltotalofferprice;
?>

<input name="shipping" type="radio" value="100"/>Shipped
<input type="radio" name="shipping" value="0" checked="checked"/>Not Shipped

<tr><td>total Offer price: </td><td><span id="total"></span></td></tr>
```

Then you need to setup some scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //We don't want this to change, so lets keep this as a "const"
   const originalTotal = '<?php echo $_SESSION['fulltotalofferprice1'];?>';

   //We add a listener to changes in the radios
   $( 'input[name="shipping"]' ).on('click change', function () {

       //the changed/clicked radio
       let that = $( this );

       //if the radio is checked
       if( that.is( ':checked' ) ) {

           //Add the radio value to the original value
           let total = originalTotal + that.val();

           //Set the text of the span
           $( '#total' ).text( total );

           //update the session var with a ajax post
           $.post('update-session-total-shipping.php', { total });

       }

   } );
</script>
```

Now that you have the scripts, you need to create a `php` file to receive and update the total value, we will call it "update-session-total-shipping.php" in this example :

```
//check if the total has a value
if( isset( $_POST[ 'total' ] ) )
{
    //set as the new total
    $_SESSION[ 'fulltotalofferprice1' ] = $_POST[ 'total' ];
}
```

The rest is up to you, good luck, never stop your learning.